# Регулярка заменить символ на 0

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(itcl.number, '[^0-9]+', '0') from itcl;
```

Я хочу заменить все символы, даже точки и запятые, и тире, и двоеточие на 0.

Если зайти на сайт регулярок и протестить, то выражения  `'[^0-9]+'` более чем достаточно для такой замены.

Но если в postgresql, в поле number записано **007.12.22-02:08:02**, то оно таким и остаётся.

Как правильно внести изменения, чтобы в постгре это **007.12.22-02:08:02** превращалось в  **007012022002008002**

Answer (score 3):

Если бы вы были чуть внимательней, то увидели бы что ваш пример все же меняет исходную строку. Только он меняет первое вхождение.

Собственно этот момент и описан в документации. Написано что меняется первая подстрока, попадающая под условие. Если же нужно поменять все, то нужно использовать флаг **g**

Вот такой пример работает:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('007.12.22-02:08:02', '[^0-9]', '0', 'g')
```

Comment: с флагом этим всся формула не пашет

Comment: Сейчас вот на базе еще раз проверил. select REGEXP_REPLACE('007.12.22-02:08:02', '[^0-9]', '0', 'g') возвращает  *007012022002008002*